# How do I setup only python 2.7 in a docker container?

Tags: python, node.js, docker, dockerfile

I have node app and in one use case I am calling python script from node using [`python-shell`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) . I am trying to setup this app on docker and my Dockerfile looks something like this:

```
FROM debian:latest
# replace shell with bash so we can source files
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
# update the repository sources list
# and install dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y curl \
&& apt-get -y autoclean
# nvm environment variables
ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 10.15.3
# install nvm
# https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install-script
RUN curl --silent -o-https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.2/install.sh | bash

# install node and npm
RUN source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
&& nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
&& nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
&& nvm use default
# add node and npm to path so the commands are available
ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH
# confirm installation
RUN node -v
RUN npm -v
RUN apt-get -y install python2.7
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm","run","start"]
```

after building and running this container when I try to invoke use case where python script gets called from node I am getting this error.

```
null
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn /usr/lib/python2.7 EACCES
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

Help on setting up just python2.7 in a docker container?

Comment: Note that, in the same way the answers suggest the `python` image, there is [a standard `node` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) as well.  Using a version manager like `nvm` in a Dockerfile adds unnecessary complication.  Consider using the POSIX `.` built-in to "source" files rather than the bash-specific `source` extension.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use python base image

```
FROM python:2.7
```

This base image with have python pre-configured and you don't need to install python seperately. Hope it helps.

Here is the [list](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/?tab=tags&page=2) of available image

For quick reference please check
https://blog.realkinetic.com/building-minimal-docker-containers-for-python-applications-37d0272c52f3

Comment: are you sure image name is PYTHON2.7:latest? because I am getting an error that it should be lowercase and even lowercase isn't working. `pull access denied for python2.7, the repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'`

Comment: Updated the answer 

https://hub.docker.com/_/python/?tab=tags&page=2 and you can find list of images.

Answer (score 3):

You can use "FROM python:2.7" , the base image.

```css
FROM python:2.7

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "./your-daemon-or-script.py" ]
```

[(documentation link)please find some examples here](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/python/)