# Docker: python has no installation candidate

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I am trying to create a docker image from my docker file which has the following content:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest 
WORKDIR /app 
ADD . /app 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install python -y 
CMD python /app/main.py 
LABEL color=red
```

which fails with the following error:

apt-get update && apt-get install python -y returned a non-zero code: 100
[image: Error]

So please help me in solving this error

Comment: Don't post images. Share the text of Dockerfile and logs. Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Dockerfile text is : FROM ubuntu:latest
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install python -y
CMD python /app/main.py
LABEL color=red

Comment: Please [edit] the question and replace the images with the text.

Comment: The error message tells you the distro at hand does not have a package named `python`. Do you have any reason to believe that to be untrue? Try `python2` or `python3`, as appropriate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Docker is just Linux. When some `apt-get install acme` fails, almost always is due to linux, not docker.

To find the solution the first step is to replicate the error in a clean or new linux machine.

### Replicating your issue

To replicate your error in a clean linux I created an empty linux with: `docker run -it ubuntu:latest`

Then, inside the container I ran your `apt-get update && apt-get install python -y`. I got your error:

[image]

### Solution

In this specifically case, since you are using `FROM ubuntu:latest`, in this year(2023) the latest ubuntu image don't allow by default **python2**

So, I if you try with `apt-get install python3 -y`, it will work. Finally your Dockerfile should be:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest 
WORKDIR /app 
ADD . /app 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install python3 -y 
CMD python3 /app/main.py 
LABEL color=red
```

### Older Python

If your code needs old python version, you should not use `FROM ubuntu:latest` because in the latest version of ubuntu, only python3 is allowed by default.

In case you need python2, you should research on internet one of these options:

- The exact steps to install python2 on latest ubuntu (20 or 22). Then put these steps in your Dockerfile

  - [How do I setup only python 2.7 in a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55625146/how-do-i-setup-only-python-2-7-in-docker-container)
- Search some docker image with yout desired python version

  - https://hub.docker.com/layers/python/library/python/2.7.18-slim-stretch/images/sha256-a0b3c65a15ba08138460de9fd2267b8dec30ed98407a0edac0adc0ccbe809cad?context=explore
  - https://github.com/Docker-Hub-frolvlad/docker-alpine-python2